# How to extend the output of a window function with missing dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table looking like this:

```
    > DESC sensordata;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| device_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timestamp | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ...                                                              |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

*(I know calling the datetime field `timestamp` was not great as it is a keyword)*

Minimal reproducable example:

```
CREATE TABLE `sensordata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `sensordata` VALUES
  (1,1,'2020-01-01 13:10:00'),
  (2,1,'2020-01-02 13:20:00'),
  (3,1,'2020-01-04 13:40:00'),
  (4,2,'2020-01-01 13:10:00'),
  (5,2,'2020-01-02 13:10:00'),
  (6,2,'2020-01-04 13:10:00'),
  (7,2,'2020-01-04 13:10:00'),
  (8,2,'2020-01-04 13:10:00'),
  (9,2,'2020-01-04 13:10:00'),
  (10,2,'2020-01-05 13:10:00');
```

I want to get the increasing count of rows in this table, grouped by device_id and timestamp. So far I got this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(timestamp)) as time, 
       CAST(device_id as CHAR) as device, 
       count(id) OVER (PARTITION BY device ORDER BY time) AS sum 
   FROM sensordata
```

It nearly gives me what I want:

```
+------------+--------+-----+
| time       | device | sum |
+------------+--------+-----+
| 2020-01-01 | 1      |   1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 1      |   2 |
| 2020-01-04 | 1      |   3 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2      |   1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 2      |   2 |
| 2020-01-04 | 2      |   6 |
| 2020-01-05 | 2      |   7 |
+------------+--------+-----+
```

As you see the sum increases correctly with the time. But I need to also include the dates on which the sum doesn't change, so the table should look like this:

```
+------------+--------+-----+
| time       | device | sum |
+------------+--------+-----+
| 2020-01-01 | 1      |   1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 1      |   2 |
| 2020-01-03 | 1      |   2 |
| 2020-01-04 | 1      |   3 |
| 2020-01-05 | 1      |   3 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2      |   1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 2      |   2 |
| 2020-01-03 | 2      |   2 |
| 2020-01-04 | 2      |   6 |
| 2020-01-05 | 2      |   7 |
+------------+--------+-----+
```

How to include the missing dates with the correct sums in this context? Is this feasible with the used window function?

edit: added a reproducible example

edit2: extended example with more rows per day and device

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Akina Yes, this is what I was trying but couldn't get to work. Will try to give a MCRE later.

Comment: @Akina I did add a MRE. Still can't get it right, I think it is because I don't really understand the window function. Maybe there is a solution for this without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 AS
( SELECT DATE(MIN(`timestamp`)) ts
  FROM sensordata
UNION ALL
  SELECT ts + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  FROM cte1
  WHERE ts < ( SELECT DATE(MAX(`timestamp`)) ts
               FROM sensordata ) ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT device_id
          FROM sensordata )
SELECT DISTINCT
       cte1.ts, 
       cte2.device_id, 
       COUNT(sensordata.id) OVER ( PARTITION BY cte2.device_id
                                   ORDER BY cte1.ts ) `sum`
FROM cte1
CROSS JOIN cte2
LEFT JOIN sensordata ON cte1.ts = DATE(sensordata.`timestamp`)
                    AND cte2.device_id = sensordata.device_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=055325fe03894e87648a95e5ba3e3bc7)

Comment: Thank you, I think I mostly understand whats happening there. One thing I stupidly didn't include in my example is that there are many rows per day and device_id, which makes the output of your query overly redundant: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60f4301b21b1b2c358993f7e8cf8034c how to solve this?

Comment: @JohnAlba Update your question with extended source data and expected result for it.